# Problem rendering the result set columns names with interface projection method names - Fetching Multiple Columns from Multiple Tables

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, projection

I need multiple columns from multiple tables data.

Using Native Query:

```
@Query(value = "select t1.name as name, t1.phone as phone, t2.address as address, t2.pincode as pincode 
from tablet t1, table2 t2 
where t1.id=t2.tab1_id", nativeQuery = true)
List<MultipleColumnValues> getMultipleColumnsFromMultipleTables();
```

The return type of the above Query is a List of below projection:

```
public interface MultipleColumnValues {
     String getName();
     String getPhone();
     String getAddress();
     String getPincode();
}
```

I am getting the List successfully.
But:
The results are storing in different variables like,
The column names in the query mentioned are not rendering properly with the projection method Names.

eg: column 'name'(db query) value is stored in getPincode(), 
and pincode(db Query) is stored in getAddress()

How to render/map the result set names with the exact projection method names correctly?

Comment: Can you try to add "as" like "t1.name as name"

Comment: @SimonMartinelli edited my question as suggested

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Which Spring Boot version are you using?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli spring boot version -1.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Spring Data JPA version that is used in Spring Boot 1.5.2.

You have to upgrade to 1.5.3 then everything will work.

That't link to the issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-927

Comment: I don't know who downvoted your question. But did you try 1.5.3?

Comment: my project updating to a newer version have few restrictions at office. but i tried shuffling the select columns in native query to render to my interface projection, and it is now resulting proper. later i checked in multiple work spaces, it is working fine.

Comment: Also, i have other teams who are working on Spring Boot 2.2.0, and they are also using similar approach, and they never faced these issues. I guess your guess is right. Thanks for your time @simon Martinelli

Comment: Yes sure it's valid